# How to log pod's outgoing HTTP requests in kubernetes?

Tags: http, logging, kubernetes, bandwidth

I have a kubernetes cluster with running pods. In order to monitor and troubleshoot the infrastructure, I want to implement a centralized logging solution so all incoming and outgoing HTTP requests will be logged within one place.

For the incoming requests this is not a problem at all, I can use nginx log from ingress controller and present it.

I also understand that I can log outgoing requests inside the application I run in pod, but the problem is that applications from outside developers are also used and it may not contain logging implementation.

As for the outgoing requests, there is no any solution provided by default if I understand it right. I have explored k8s logging and k8s audit, but it does not provide such feature.

Probably, I need some network sniffer, but it is quite a low-level solution for such problem as I can see. So, the question is: is there any out-of-the-box implementation for such demand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at a service mesh solution like [Istio](https://istio.io) or [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io) as well as tracing solutions like [Jaeger](https://uber.github.io/jaeger/) or [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io). With these you can build to have full observability on how information flows in/out and through your kube cluster